# How to replace a textual address into a hyperlinked "word" in Word

Tags: microsoft-word, microsoft-word-2013, hyperlink

I have a table with hundreds of link addresses which I need to replace with a hyperlinked word. Consider the following:

I have a table with `www.example.com/1` and `www.example.com/2` as the cells' content. I need to (preferably automatically) replace them with the word `Link` and make this `Link` hyperlink to `www.example.com/1` and `www.example.com/2` respectively.

Is there some way through Find and Replace or a Macro, maybe, which I can use?

PS. If it's of any help, I'm making a resume on MS Word 2013.

Comment: [Find and replace text by using regular expressions (Advanced)](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/Find-and-replace-text-by-using-regular-expressions-Advanced-eeaa03b0-e9f3-4921-b1e8-85b0ad1c427f)

Comment: I looked at the page. My problem is not finding the links i.e. using wildcards. It's  that I can't replace all of them (1, 2, 3, 4, etc.) with the word "Link" (or any other word for that matter) and at the same time make "Link" hyperlink to the relavent address (1, 2, 3, 4, etc.) which it has replaced. I really hope I could make myself clear. Did I?

Comment: [Replacing Plain Text with a Hyperlink](http://wordribbon.tips.net/T008692_Replacing_Plain_Text_with_a_Hyperlink.html)

Answer (score 0):

Okay I found a way to do this but it's more of a workaround.

Note that this worked in Excel not Word as I had intended.

First I used the instructions from [**here**](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2595692/how-do-i-convert-a-column-of-text-urls-into-active-hyperlinks-in-excel) to make all of the addresses into actual hyperlinks.

Then I `Find and Replace`d all the hyperlinks to the word `Link`.

Like I said, workaround. But at least it worked.

Answer (score 0):

You can do this with HTML:

1. Save the document as a webpage (Save As and then choose Webpage in the File Type menu)
2. Open the webpage with Notepad
3. Press CTRL+H to open the Replace dialog box
4. In Search, write `www.example.com` and in Replace With, write `<a href="http://www.example.com` and press the Replace All button
5. In Search, write `</td>` and in Replace With, write `">Link</a></td>` and press the Replace All button
6. Save the webpage and close Notepad
7. Open the webpage with Word
8. Save the document as a Word document (Save As and then choose Word Document in the File Type menu)